# Get list id from open view page via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I have included some javascript in SharePoint master page, I need this javascript to have access to the opened list ID.

For example when I load

```
 www.mypage.com/codev/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Lists/All Fields/AllItems.aspx
```

I need my JavaScript function to have access to the list: All Fields  ID.

Notice there is no query string. I suppose I could extract the list name from the URL but as I'm trying to make it work on any site/list combination I was hoping there would be an easier way to extract the current opened list ID's GUID.

Answer (score 3):

At least two options are available to determine List Id on View page:

### Option 1: [SP.ListOperation.Selection Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407815.aspx)

[SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410971%28v=office.14%29.aspx) gets the ID of the list being selected by the client user. The following example will return List Id in a View page.

Example:

```
var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
```

### Option 2: `spPageContextInfo` client context

With every page is associated client context (`_spPageContextInfo` object), that object contains List Id when the View page is rendered. The following example demonstrates how to get List Id in View page.

Example:

```
//get current List Id in View page
var listId = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the ctx variable. There's lots of great info in there.  In your case, what you need is:

```
ctx.listName
```